# Strange behaviour with docker-py

Tags: docker, python

Consider the following setup.

Precondition: have a healthy image i.e. service starts up.

E.g.

```
docker run -d IMAGE
```

Then, with the Python plugin docker-py, consider the following code which should be equivalent, only with added port mapping.

```
ingreedy = client.containers.create("openfoodbroker/ingreedy.service", 
                                     name="ingreedy_service",
                                     detach=True,
                                     ports={'5000': 5000})
print(ingreedy.id)
```

This code prints out the container ID and I can remove the container using `docker rm -f`, but:

- port 5000 is not open;
- the container does not show up on `docker ps`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`docker.containers.create()` is [documented](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html) to:

> Create a container without starting it. Similar to `docker create`.

Either call `docker.containers.run()` instead, or given the container object returned from `create()`, call `ingreedy.start()`.

(`docker ps` by default only shows running containers; `docker ps -a` should show the container in a "created" state.)

Comment: ahh thank you!!